# Selenium (Python): getAttribute('value') not working to get text from text input

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm trying to get the text from a text input. I understand from Stackoverflow that I should use `getAttribute('value')`. This is what I'm trying but it's not working (below). I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getAttribute'

```
audience_panel = self.browser.find_element_by_id('input-panel')
network_text = audience_panel.find_element_by_id('network-code')
self.assertEqual(network_text.getAttribute("value"), "ABC")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getAttribute()` is Java syntax. Try `get_attribute()` instead.